# What is a good, simple and free HTML editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, html, text-editing

Are there any good, simple and free HTML editors for Windows out there?

Something that a user with no experience can build a simple page with.

I'm looking for something like the old [FrontPage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_FrontPage) application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [html-kit](https://www.htmlkit.com/).
Or [Komodo Edit](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit).

Comment: html-kit could be a good choice...Let's wait and see if something simpler comes along in another answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/download.php) is good.  [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) is free as well, if not a bit more heavy weight for just HTML.

Comment: Notepad++ might be hard to use with no experience.

Answer (score 4):

[Nvu](http://net2.com/nvu/index.html) and/or [KompoZer](http://www.kompozer.net/).  I thought Nvu was dead, but perhaps not.  KompoZer supposedly picked up where Nvu left off.  I've used them both and I'd say they certainly qualify as "simple and free".

Answer (score 2):

[Mozilla SeaMonkey](http://www.seamonkey-project.org) has a basic HTML editing capability that's actually not too bad for a beginner doing some simple editing.

Answer (score 0):

Do they already have the publishing and hosting side of things taken care of? Dealing with those can be quite daunting for the less technically-inclined. If not, and/or you want something really easy for them, go with a solution like [Wordpress.com](http://wordpress.com), [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com), or even [SquareSpace](http://squarespace.com). All of these are capable of building decent sites.

Comment: It is for creating small files locally.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the [Cuffeecup HTML editor](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor) a lot. I often recommend it to our customers when they are looking for an editor.