# What WYSIWYG HTML editor should I give a novice

Tags: editing, html, wysiwyg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any free open source HTML editors?](https://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors)

I have a friend who wants to have a simple website for his business. But he is a total HTML novice.
I'm willing to set up his hosting for him, and teach him how to upload content to it. I'll even stub out the web site for him. However, I don't want to maintain it for the rest of eternity - so I'd like to set him up with a WYSIWYG HTML editor.

What should I set him up with? (I prefer Free of course, but I don't care if its open-source or not)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for both you and that friend if you set up a simple CMS instead?

Comment: Nope, don't want to be responsible for it.

Comment: Why would you be responsible for a CMS? Most CMS systems have easy management features that allow you to create and maintain a website with zero knowledge of HTML or programming.

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/)** is very nice, easy to use and novice-friendly.

> KompoZer is a complete web authoring
>   system that combines web file
>   management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG 
>   web page editing.
>
> KompoZer is designed to be extremely
>   easy to use, making it ideal for
>   non-technical computer users who want
>   to create an attractive,
>   professional-looking web site without
>   needing to know HTML or web coding.

[image]

> teach him how to upload content to it.

KompoZer can also connect to an FTP account and upload (publish) pages.

And here's a little tutorial that will get your friend started:

**[How to Design and Publish Your Website with KompoZer](http://www.thesitewizard.com/gettingstarted/kompozer-tutorial-1.shtml)**

*KompoZer is free open source software (FOSS), a portable version is available [here](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/nvu_portable).*

Answer (score 7):

Here are a handfull of answer from Super User:

[suggest-good-and-simple-wysiwyg-website-editor-and-hosting](https://superuser.com/questions/87640/suggest-good-and-simple-wysiwyg-website-editor-and-hosting)

[are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors](https://superuser.com/questions/19662/are-there-any-free-open-source-html-editors)

[what-is-a-good-simple-and-free-html-editor-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/11752/what-is-a-good-simple-and-free-html-editor-for-windows)

[what-free-online-alternatives-are-there-to-frontpage](https://superuser.com/questions/33920/what-free-online-alternatives-are-there-to-frontpage)

[free-html-editor-for-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/90894/free-html-editor-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

You want [Cushy CMS](http://www.cushycms.com/).  It's a simple online editor for web pages.  You create a shell, add a class name to a div or other tag and voila! it's editable on the Cushy page.

It's very easy - I use it with all my non-saavy HTML users.

Answer (score 2):

give him a lesson or two in basic html - let him know you're a phone call away. WYSIWYG causes more problems than it solves in my opinion. HTML isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SquareSpace](http://www.squarespace.com) , they offer a free trial.

I heard about it on [CrankyGeeks](http://www.crankygeeks.com), which is an awesome tech show for cranky geeks !

They might have a referral code for further discount too :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a job for [Surreal CMS](http://surrealcms.com/).