# Application for creating webpages for users without skills?

Tags: software-rec, webpage

Is there some kind WYSIWYG application for creating webpages for users without skills?

What I would like from that?

- Easy to use
- Deployment via FTP
- Validate html/xhtml
- Without server-side scripting, just only html, css and image files

**UPDATE**
My target user hasn't any knowledge about html and css or about programming.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/110072/what-wysiwyg-html-editor-should-i-give-a-novice seems very closely related

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Dreamweaver is the most popular WYSIWYG website creator. It has a built-in FTP client, handles linking between stylesheets, images and HTML pages, and has a host of other features. If you absolutely must use a WYSIWYG editor, and can afford (or already have) Adobe CS, check it out.

However, with any WYSIWYG HTML editor, you will run into eventual problems. Even when hand-crafting code, it is often difficult to achieve cross-browser compatibility; visual editors are even less precise. Sites created in WYSIWYG editors tend to be lower quality, not to mention a pain in the rear to update.

While I don't know the specifics of your situation, if possible, you might want to look into setting up some type of content management system where users could log in and make basic changes to their own portion of a site, while maintaining a consistent theme and having a more easily updatable system. Popular CMSs include [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), [SilverStripe](http://silverstripe.org/) and [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/).

Depending on the complexity you need, you might even be able to get by with something as simple as one of the many online site building tools. [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/) is one option; there are dozens more.

Comment: Nice answer. But I want something very simply. Dreamweaver is to complicated. CMSs is great, but they need lot of configuration before user creates simple webpage.

Comment: I politely disagree, MicTech - a platform like wordpress.com is very rapid to get started. Even wordpress.org (ie self-hosted) should not be a huge hassle if you can find a good theme to install and get going. Don't forget most blogging systems allow for pages (ie permanent content) as well as the 'blog' part which is date-based.

Comment: +1 but these WYSIWYG editors can only take you so far. I would go on an start learning HTML and javascript, only that way you can get the skills to create a good looking "fully functional" webpage